# cron: send errors to syslog, instead of MTA

Tags: cron, syslog, error-handling

I don't have `MTA` installed on my desktop.

Whenever there is a problem with a `cronjob` script, I see this in my logs:

```
CRON:  (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

A script that was supposed to be run by `cron` generated an error, and `cron` wanted to send me the error per email.

But I would like to see the error in my log instead, ie being logged normally to `syslog`, same as the above `info` message.

Is it possible to tell `cron` to forget about `MTA`, and log everything, including errors, to local `syslog` ?

## UPDATE

the solution from @roaima works well for my original problem as stated.
But I have realized I need more sophisticated syntax for my `cronjob`, where `stdout` from `command1` is piped to `command2` and `stderr` (from both?) is piped to `command3`.

Here is a concrete example (simplified):

```
0 * * * * mysqldump mydb | ifne xz > "/tmp/$(date +\%F).sql.xz" | logger -t mysqldump -p cron.err
```

In the abova example, I need to send stdout from `mysqldump` to `ifne xz` and only if either `mysqldump` or `ifne xz` generate error do I need to pipe it to logger.

This syntax needs to  works in `dash` (`/bin/sh`)

Comment: Your edit constitutes a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the logger subsystem. There are two variants, depending on whether you have `systemd` installed or not.

1. With `systemd` - using `systemd-cat`

   ```
   echo This is a test with systemd-cat | systemd-cat -t mytest -p info
   ```

   This writes a message to the journal logger (see `journalctl`) and also through to the legacy system logging subsystem where you'll find the output in `/var/log/syslog`, etc.

   ```
   journalctl -t mytest
   -- Logs begin at Thu 2020-05-21 07:41:00 UTC, end at Mon 2020-06-01 13:34:56 UTC. --
   Jun 01 13:34:56 pi mytest[24236]: This is a test through systemd-cat
   ```
2. With `syslog` - using `logger`

   ```
   echo This is a test with logger | logger -t mytest -p local0.info
   ```

   This writes a message through the syslog subsystem (see `rsyslog.conf` or similar) where you'll find the output in `/var/log/syslog`, etc.

   ```
   tail /var/log/syslog
   [...]
   Jun  1 13:34:56 pi mytest[24236]: This is a test through systemd-cat
   Jun  1 13:38:28 pi mytest: This is a test through logger
   ```

To use one of these logging options just append to your `cron` job, adjusting the tag name (`myscript`) and priority (`info`) in the example

```
0 * * * * /path/to/script 2>&1 | systemd-cat -t myscript -p info
```

Now that you have provided a concrete example, where you want *stdout* to get written to a target data file but you want to log *stderr*, you can use this

```
0 * * * * ( mysqldump mydb | ifne xz > "/tmp/$(date +\%F).sql.xz" ) 2>&1 | logger -t mysqldump -p cron.err
```

Comment: I don't have systemd, so I will use `logger`. But do I have to do this for each script/each line in crontab? Can't I set this globally? Where is the `MTA` configured in cron? Why does cron look for MTA? Can it be changed, or is it hardcoded?

Comment: I assumed you didn't want to install an MTA, because that would have been an obvious solution to the problem (error message, "_No MTA installed [...]_"). With an MTA you'll get error messages in the local spool directory, `/var/mail/$USER`

Comment: thank, that works perfectly.